# Jax-ws can't get params from operation with default namespace

Tags: java, web-services, namespaces, jax-ws, xml-namespaces

Interface:

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.DOCUMENT, use = SOAPBinding.Use.ENCODED, parameterStyle = SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface WebServ {

    @WebMethod(action = "Sum", operationName = "Sum")
    public abstract String sum(@WebParam(name = "a") int a, @WebParam(name = "b") int b);

}
```

---

Implementation:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.company.wstest.WebServ")
public class WebServImpl implements WebServ {
    @Override
    public String sum(@WebParam(name = "a") int a, @WebParam(name = "b") int b) {
        return String.valueOf(a + b);
    }
}
```

---

Publish:

```
String endPoint = "http://localhost:" + port + "/" + env;
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.publish(endPoint, new WebServImpl());
if (endpoint.isPublished()) {
    System.out.println("Web service published for '" + env + "' environment");
    System.out.println("Web service url: " + endPoint);
    System.out.println("Web service wsdl: " + endPoint + "?wsdl");
}
```

---

If I send from SoapUI such request (which is automatically generated from wsdl):

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wst="http://wstest.company.com/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <wst:Sum>
         <a>6</a>
         <b>7</b>
      </wst:Sum>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I receive correct answer:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:SumResponse xmlns:ns2="http://wstest.company.com/">
         <return>13</return>
      </ns2:SumResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

But what I actually need, it's to send request with default namespace:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Header/>
   <Body>
      <Sum xmlns="http://wstest.company.com/">
         <a>6</a>
         <b>7</b>
      </Sum>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

and response is:

```
...
<return>0</return>
...
```

how I understand this parameters (a and b) are null.. it is strange, because jax-ws parsed request without errors. It sees Operation, but not parameters. Do someone know what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**: "a" and "b" inherit namespace "http://wstest.company.com/" from their parent "Sum".

**Solution**: set them the same targetNamespace in @WebService and @WebParam (to use the same default namespace for "a", "b" and "Sum"):

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.company.wstest.WebServ", targetNamespace = "http://wstest.company.com/")
public class WebServImpl implements WebServ {
    @Override
    public String sum(@WebParam(name = "a", targetNamespace = "http://wstest.company.com/") int a
                     ,@WebParam(name = "b", targetNamespace = "http://wstest.company.com/") int b) {
        return String.valueOf(a + b);
    }
}
```